# Config.php issue in WordPress

Tags: wp-query, errors

have recently Encountered an issue on my website. Not sure when or how this happened.

I am getting the following message displayed on-top of all my web-pages on this specific site.

” Notice: Constant FS_CHMOD_DIR already defined in /home/mc4ebqy52sd6/public_html/khwajagharibnawaz.org/wp-config.php on line 101 ”

The website is  khwajagharibnawaz.org

I am a armature on WordPress however,I had a look at the config.php file and the l01 line is just a text line stating the following :

100* For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
101* visit the Codex.
102*
Any help to resolve this issue would be highly appreciative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for `FS_CHMOD_DIR` in wp-config.php. You can only define constants once. If it's defined multiple times, you will get a PHP notice.

Notices aren't often a cause for concern, but they can reveal places you may have issues across the site. You can disable these from displaying to your visitors by defining `WP_DEBUG` as false.

Comment: Thank you! That sorted it. I changed the line  define('WP_DEBUG', true); to define('WP_DEBUG', false);    ... You'r are a life saver Mr MikeNGarrett. God bless you!

Comment: @tarmhd keep in mind that you just hid the issues by doing this. They're still present and should be fixed. Hopefully now you have a bit more time to fix them. :-)

Comment: Well! I did cheat initially by defining WP_DEBUG as false then, your last message persisted me to go back and resolve things properly. I found  constants defined more than twice. All fully resolved now.. Cheers!